# Push notifications with custom sounds and vibration when the screen is locked in Codename One

Tags: android, push-notification, codenameone, android-vibration

I tried to place a file under /native/android/res/raw/bellbox.wav and add the build hint android.pushSound = bellbox but this does not work. At the moment it is not playing any sound also, I tried modifying the vibration pattern with the build hint android.pushVibratePattern = 1000 and did not have any luck either.

Please help me, thanks

Comment: Are you using the Codename One push servers to send a push message? Is your phone muted? Which OS version is installed on your device and what's the device brand?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the Codename One push servers. My phone is not muted, is a Moto G with Android Lollipop 5.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the file under /native/android/raw/bellbox.wav

Comment: Thanks Chen, this works for me, do you have any idea on what to do for the vibration pattern?